# rotate and translate coordinate system along with object in animation in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Iam trying to animate differential turning of two wheels. I am doing with key frame based animation. In differential turning, after rotating the wheel by some calculated angle, I want the coordinate system also to rotate with the wheel so that calculations are based with respect to the new coordinate system. How do I achieve this in wpf C#.
Basically I want to rotate the coordinate system about a point and set that as the new coordinate system.
How do I achieve this?

```
CylinderGeometry cgRL = (CylinderGeometry)this.Resources["cylinder1"];
rotateRL_Z.CenterX = axleRL_RR + distanceRL_RR / 2;
rotateRL_Z.CenterY = 0;
rotateRL_Z.Rotation = new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1), -rotRL_RR);
```

(axleRL_RR + distanceRL_RR / 2) is the radius with which the cylinder should rotate.rotateRL_Z.CenterX , rotateRL_Z.CenterY are the X and Y coordinates for the point about which the rotation should take place. Now, when it moves to the new location in key frame animation, the X coordinate is calculated based on the old coordinate system. I want the coordinate system to be fixed to the cylinder center and rotate along with it.

Comment: Is there any practical difference between rotating the object and rotating everything except for the object?

Comment: Sound fun.. Post some code, not a ton... Make a new view just that issue and animation request and maybe a little pseudo so that I'm on the same page and I'll get on it.

Comment: Ok I understand.  If you're using a storyboard the value you start the storyboard is the value you must use throughout the entire storyboard.  That doesn't mean the storyboard must finish it just means that value can't be altered.  What you can do is put an object inside of an object and animate them both.  If you animate a button left and the grid containing the button is animated down then the button will go left and down. Does that help?  To make animations completely dynamic you will need to continuously start a new dynamic storyboard or drop storyboard and make your own animation logic.

Comment: If you want to make your own animation logic you will need to work the logic on a background thread or other task and update the properties on the UI thread.  This can be done because I've done it.  Make sure to add your own frequency to the animation like you would in a Game sprite.  If this is what you're looking for an lost let me know.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII I want the coordinate system to orient and move with the object. Right now the coordinate system is fixed and all calculations are made with respect to this coordinate system. So, I want the coordinate system to move and orient with the cylinder center. How do I achieve this.

Comment: I've actually just finished a project that did something very similar.  I think this is where we need to move from comments to a conversation that we can pass code and when we get the answer we'll post it.  But to try and explain in my next 356 characters. If you are rotating a square in a canvas clockwise, lets say for 360° in a second, and we also rotate the Canvas clockwise the same then the Square will animate around 720° in one second.  Likewise if you rotate the Canvas counter-clockwise the same then the Square will never move.  Make sense?

Comment: So, without seeing all of the code I suggest animating your plane or coordinate system as you're animating your wheel or whatever.